# How to create a script to run the jar (while installing SBT)?

Tags: java, scala, jar, installation, sbt

I am installing SBT on Mac. I am following the instructions mentioned (cryptically) on [the website](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html). I am now at the stage ['Installing sbt manually'](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Manual-Installation.html). Under 'Unix', it reads:

> Put sbt-launch.jar in ~/bin.
>
> Create a script to run the jar, by creating ~/bin/sbt with these contents:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
> java $SBT_OPTS -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
> ```
>
> Make the script executable:
>
> ```
> $ chmod u+x ~/bin/sbt
> ```

I have put sbt-launch.jar in the correct folder. But I do not understand what the rest means. How can you create the script: in the terminal? Is the code to make the script executable something that you have to execute once in the terminal?

(And after finishing the installation, how will you be able to open SBT?)

Comment: Yes. You create the script (a text file) and make it executable once, then you add `$HOME/bin` to your `PATH` (presumably in your profile or bashrc file) and then you execute `sbt` from the command line.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OK, I have made the executable script and have put it in `/usr/local/bin/sbt`. Could you give more information about "then you add `$HOME/bin to your PATH` (presumably in your profile or bashrc file)"? (I rarely use the terminal, so sorry if it is a basic question.)

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is probably already in your `PATH`. Your instructions said `~/bin/` which is `$HOME/bin`

Comment: there is no cryptic messages, if you are not familiar with handling `tar.gz` just use `port` or `brew` then its very straight forward

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Your comments answered my question. I did not know how to create the file and make it executable, nor how to add it to the path. Although I do not know if this question in total is very useful to other people, I invite you to reformulate your comments as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for you to install sbt on macOS without much terminal interaction is [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). It's a popular package manager and it likely will be useful for you in the future. So just click the link and follow the instruction to install (it's just one command to paste to the terminal). The run

```
brew install sbt
```

That's it. Now to launch sbt you just run `sbt` command in a folder with your projects. Actually, these instructions are on the sbt web-site in the section ['Installing sbt on Mac'](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Mac.html).

So if you are following 'Installing sbt manually' on purpose, the "Create a script" part means just to create a "text file" in any editor you use, paste those lines in it, and save to the proper location. Then run `chmod` command in the terminal. That's it.

About adding something to `PATH` check [this article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/).